# How to inspect variables in a FAKE script?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, f#-fake

I have a bug in my FAKE script in obscure code were I interface with legacy build infrastructure. I have a bug there and I wanted to debug my script in Visual Studio. I used `--break` flag to attach Visual Studio 2013 debugger and I could set up a break point. But I cannot inspect any of variables of a FAKE script.

Is there a way to use Visual Studio 2013 debugger to inspect state of FAKE script? There seems to no problems with regular F# programs.

Comment: Is this question still relevant to you or do you have answer, possibly even one working in VS2015?

Comment: Would it not suffice to `trace` the required variables?

Comment: @AlexM Cluttering the whole build script with traces can help but I'd prefer a "step-into"-like experience as you have in VS or any decent debugger along with stacktrace and variables on stack. The difference is in orders of a magnitude in effort, flexibility and frustration. TL;DR: no

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the REPL to invoke your build script a bit at a time?

[An example of using VS Code + the ionide plugin to use the FSI interactive Repl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-vscode#writing-some-code)

You should be able to highlight and run parts of your script in the REPL.